# php file saved in /var/www/html/fold/folder does not run in browser

Tags: apache2, php, browser

[image]

I want to run a project in ubuntu so I created a Demo with `index.php` but instead of running in browser it keeps on downloading the file.

I have apache running.

> What am I missing?

[image: Second image]

I just notice that my url is incorrect so I change to: ***http://localhost/html/ToDoList/Demo/***

still not getting what I desire.

Tried `The requested URL /html/ToDoList/Demo/index.php was not found on this server.`

Comment: We'd need to see your Apache configurations, but my guess is you didn't install the PHP extensions and enable them, and didn't specify to Apache that the Index page (index.php) is the proper file to serve when you don't specify a full path and just a path to a directory.

Comment: @ThomasWard i will post the apache configuration give me a minute to find them

Comment: @ThomasWard when running `sudo systemctl status apache2` is this the setting you need to see?

Comment: did you install libapache2-mod-php7.0 `sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.0` (or whatever version corresponds to your version of Ubuntu  ?

Comment: @Panther yes i get this one `Reading state information... Done
libapache2-mod-php7.0 is already the newest version (7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 252 not upgraded.
`

Comment: Restart apache, clear your cache, check the permissions of your php file(s). See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#Troubleshooting_PHP_5 . Apache will not run php via your file:/// , you have to run in by url `http://localhost/ToDoList/Demo/index.php`

Comment: Try `http://localhost/ToDoList/Demo/` as suggested by Panther...